# Networking with RxSwift

Tags: swift, networking, request, rx-swift, moya

I've been trying to understand rxSwift. I faced with request problem and want to implement this in a good way. Currently, I'm using this code:

```
enum RequestState<T> {
    case loading
    case loaded(T)
    case error(Error)
}

struct Response<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let data: T
    let error: ResponseError?
}

searchBar.rx.text.asObservable()
    .flatMap { self.provider.rx.request(Request(query: $0)) }
    .map({ RequestState<Response<Bool>>.loaded($0) })
    .asDriver(onErrorRecover: { error in
        return Driver.just(.error(error))
    })
    .startWith(.loading)
    .drive(onNext: { state in
        switch state {
        case .loading: ()
        case .loaded(let response): ()
        case .error(let error): ()
        }
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

This works good but not too convenient to work with data and request state. I saw in rxSwift demo project following code.

```
struct RequestState<T: Decodable> {
    let isLoading: Bool
    let data: T
    let error: ResponseError?
}

let state = viewModel.requestMethod()

state
    .map { $0.isLoading }
    .drive(self.loaderView.isOffline)
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

state
    .map { $0.data }
    .drive(tableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)

state
    .map { $0.error }
    .drive(onNext: { error in
        showAlert(error)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

And my problem in the following method, I can't understand Rx magic here:

```
func requestMethod() -> Driver<RequestState> {
    // supper code
}
```

Can someone advise me what I have to do here?

Comment: What demo project did you see this in?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I ended up with while looking at both of your code samples:

First here is the point of use:

```
    let request = searchBar.rx.text
        .unwrap()
        .map { URLRequest.search(forQuery: $0) }

    let networkRequest = createRequest(forType: MyType.self)
    let state = request
        .flatMap(networkRequest)

    state
        .map { $0.isLoading }
        .bind(to: loaderView.isOffline)
        .disposed(by: bag)

    state
        .map { $0.data }
        .unwrap()
        .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
        .disposed(by: bag)

    state
        .map { $0.error }
        .unwrap()
        .subscribe(onNext: showAlert)
        .disposed(by: bag)
```

Here is the support code for the above:

```
enum RequestState<T> {
    case loading
    case loaded(T)
    case error(Error)

    var isLoading: Bool {
        guard case .loading = self else { return false }
        return true
    }

    var data: T? {
        guard case let .loaded(t) = self else { return nil }
        return t
    }

    var error: Error? {
        guard case let .error(e) = self else { return nil }
        return e
    }
}
```

You will see that the above `RequestState` enum is a bit of an amalgamation of both `RequestState` types you showed in your example. The enum makes it easy to create the object while the computed properties make it easy to extract the information.

```
func createRequest<T>(forType type: T.Type, session: URLSession = URLSession.shared) -> (URLRequest) -> Observable<RequestState<T>> where T: Decodable {
    return { request in
        return Observable.create { observer in
            observer.onNext(.loading)
            let disposable = session.rx.data(request: request)
                .subscribe { event in
                    switch event {
                    case let .error(error):
                        observer.onNext(.error(error))
                    case let .next(data):
                        do {
                            let item = try JSONDecoder().decode(type, from: data)
                            observer.onNext(.loaded(item))
                        }
                        catch {
                            observer.onNext(.error(error))
                        }
                    case .completed:
                        observer.onCompleted()
                    }
            }
            return Disposables.create([disposable])
        }
    }
}
```

The above is a factory function. You use it to create a function that knows how to make network requests for the appropriate type. Recall in the code where it's being used I had `let networkRequest = createRequest(forType: MyType.self)`. This line produces a *function* `networkRequest` that takes a URLRequest and returns an Observable that has been specialized for the type in question.

When the Observable from `networkRequest` is subscribed to, it will immediately push out a `.loading` case, then make the request. Then it will use the response to either push out a `.loaded(T)` or an `.error(Error)` depending on the results.

Personally, I'm more inclined to use something like the ActivityIndicator system from the examples in the RxSwift repository instead.

Comment: Thank you for your example. But I'm using Moya networking manager and also want to use  Moya request method `self.provider.rx.request(Request(query: $0)` with return parameter `Single<Response>` and then work with them, instead of writing my own request method or extension for Moya.